# How to show a pop up on something is selected in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, select

[image]I know there is a onselect event which works on input and textarea elements. 
I want to show a popup like google dictionary does when something is selected on body element.
What are some possible options ?

Blue area is what I mean by selection .

Comment: Can you show what you have tried.

Comment: Why its being downvoted I asked a question I don't know. What is wrong with this ?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You could try JQuery's mouseup command - it will be triggered when you release the mouse button press at the end of your selection.

Someone else's example on JSFiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/g59KM/12/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#textarea').mousedown(function() {
        $("#alerts p").append("<span style=\"color:blue;\">Mouse down. </span>");
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        $("#alerts p").append("<span style=\"color:red;\">Mouse up. </span>");
    })
});
```

...which illustrates my point - select any of their text then when you release the mouse an event will be called, which you could use.

The JQuery instruction: [is here](https://api.jquery.com/mouseup/)